# Would the nightsky be bright (filled with starlight) without accelerating space expansion?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, cosmology, photons

As I currently understand, if a photon was emitted from a far away point in the Universe, beyond the event/particle horizon, so that the space inbetween the emitter and us is expanding faster then lightspeed, then the photon could not have/will never actually reach us.

> The particle horizon differs from the cosmic event horizon, in that the particle horizon represents the largest comoving distance from which light could have reached the observer by a specific time, while the event horizon is the largest comoving distance from which light emitted now can ever reach the observer in the future.[3]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_horizon

But as I understand, this is not the cause of the dark nightsky.

> This problem is addressed by the fact that the Big Bang theory also involves the expansion of space, which can cause the energy of emitted light to be reduced via redshift. More specifically, the extremely energetic radiation from the Big Bang has been redshifted to microwave wavelengths (1100 times the length of its original wavelength) as a result of the cosmic expansion, and thus forms the cosmic microwave background radiation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olbers%27_paradox

So it could be a reason why the nightsky is not bright, that is, filled with starlight everywhere, assuming an infinite universe, because the light has redshifted because of accelerating space expansion.

My question is, whether this redshift would be enough to make the nightsky dark even if the rate of expansion would be constant?

Question:

1. Would the nightsky be bright, that is, filled with starlight from every direction if the rate of expansion of space would be constant, assuming an infinite universe?

Comment: This is a very hypothetical question about a universe that is not ours.  There are no stars beyond the CMBR at z=1100.  The stars were still hydrogen gas at this distance (time), so we don't see any stars from further out because they are not there!  However, our sky is bright all over with blackbody radiation from the 3000 degK newly recombined hydrogen redshifted by z=1100 to 2.7 degK (peak in the microwave)...not Ober's stars.

Comment: Note constant "rate of expansion" means exponential expansion. Perhaps you mean linear expansion instead. This however is not consistent with the FRW-model. An FRW universe with some energy density expands decelerated or accelerated (or exponentially in the de Sitter case) but not linearly.

Comment: *if the rate of expansion of space would be constant,* Eventually the light will be redshifted so much that it will be in the infrared or microwave regime. In that case we would not be able to observe it. So even hypothetical it can be bright for some time but then it would not be. At least thats what am I thinking

Comment: @GaryGodfrey As the plasma you describe (which would actually make all our surroundings as bright and hot as the surface of a star) has been dissipated by that expansion of space (which is not relative motion thru space, and is consequently not subject to that local speed limit of light which itself is applicable only where curvature is neglected, i.e., when space can be considered "flat") that BB theory revealed, there's no reason to believe that stars (defined by their shape, pressure, etc.) are not extant beyond our observable region, whence they would've been carried by that expansion.

Comment: I have to add that our observable region is really our currently observable region (as some objects carried out of it by spatial expansion may return into visibility as the space occupied by our own cluster of galaxies expands into a larger proportion of a space that's potentially infinite).